# Magento 2 - System upgrade stuck at step 3 backup

Tags: magento2

I am having difficulties making magento 2 system upgrade. In step 3 of the update process I recieve errors as shown in picture.

[Magento 2 - Backup Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4izr.png)

I did a fresh install magento 2.0.5,
php 5.6.21,
ISPconfig 3.5,
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I did not change any users or permissions with chown and chmod. Disk size check with df shows that there is enough disk space available.  I assume I have to set user persmissions correctly. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

you must me having permission issue so that magento can not check the space and is not able to put the store on maintenance mode

kindly give FULL permission to apache user / group and 777 to pub and var folder

```
chown -R www-data .
chmod -R 777 pub/ var/
```

if this does not work than you can give 777 permission to magento's root folder and than put back the permission to 755

before running setup from admin

```
chmod -R 777 .
```

after successful system upgrade set required permissions

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod -R 777 pub/ var/
```

Comment: If all readiness checks fail, it can also indicate an issue with [cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html).